# why terraform unable to read my Private Key?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I started learning Terraform Getting started ( Plural sight). I was working on launching an Ec2 Instance using module_three.tf and terraform.tfvars file.

Variable Section in Module_three.tf

```
variable "aws_access_key" {}
variable "aws_secret_key" {}
variable "aws_key_path" {}
variable "aws_key_name" {}
variable "region" {
  default = "us-west-2"
}
```

terraform.tfvars file

```
aws_access_key = "ACCESS_KEY"
aws_secret_key = "SECRET_KEY"
aws_key_name = "terraform"
aws_key_path = "‪C:\\terraform\\terraform.pem"
```

`terraform plan -out m3.tfplan` doesn't give any errors. when i run  `terraform apply "m3.tfplan"` i get the below error.
`Error: Error in function call: Call to function "file" failed: failed to read ‪C:\terraform\terraform.pem.`

but to my surprise, When i check my AWS console, The instance has created and Security group also created. Just not understanding what i am doing wrong here.

```
IDE: Visual Code
OS: Ubuntu ( windows Subsystem)
terraform version: v0.12.18
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your Terraform code and the full error with surrounding context?

Comment: Based on the information available, an invalid key path would not cause the instance creation to fatally error. It would, however, prevent key pair association.